# How to make an API call using async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node.js and I'm trying to migrate the backend of my company from python to node.js

Right now I created a node.js server using express. The route works fine. My company uses WooCommerce, and they have a node.js library. My code is this one:

```
const WooCommerceAPI = require("woocommerce-api");

class WooCommerceController {
  async getOrders(req, res) {
    const orders = await WooCommerce.get("orders", function(err, data, res) {
      return res;
    });
    return res.json(orders);
  }
}

module.exports = new WooCommerceController();
```

I know that

```
WooCommerce.get("orders", function(err, data, res) {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

works, because if I execute this function it returns the list of orders of my company, however if I try to put it inside this `async` `await`, it returns the status of the WooCommerce API, not the response of the API.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your code with async await, that is not working?

Comment: `WooCommerce.get()` would need to return  a promise to use `await`. It is using a callback not promise

Comment: I believe `WooCommerce.getAsync` serves that purpose, let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WooCommerce.get` works with a callback, while `await` only works with functions that return a `Promise`. So either you need to create a promise yourself, and manually resolve it in the callback, or you can use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to automatically convert the callback-function (with an `(err, value)` callback parameters) to a Promise-style function.

```
const wooGetPromise = util.promisify(WooCommerce.get);
...
const orders = await wooGetPromise("orders");
...
```

EDIT: Thanks to RichS for looking up the API: my `wooGetPromise` already exists as `WooCommerce.getAsync`.

The options for using that function are:

1. With [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```
    WooCommerce.getAsync('orders').then(function(result) {
       return JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
    });
```

2. With [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) (only in async function):

```
    var result = await WooCommerce.getAsync('orders');
    var json = JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
```

Comment: *`await` only works with functions that return a Promise*?

Comment: See also: https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api#promified-methods (the npm  repo mispelled "promisifed"). I think the  `WooCommerce.getAsync()` method could be used... (Yeah, the library uses bluebird under the hood...)

Comment: @Ele Good point. `await` only _usefully_ works with functions that return a `Promise`.

Comment: Thank you guys! This promified methods weren't in their documentation. I had a look at the npm repo and it worked! Thank you so much for the ultra fast solution!

Comment: @Ele: That too, but that's not what I'm saying. You are talking about the function that _surrounds_ `await` (which is off-topic here). I'm talking about the value that _follows_ the `await` keyword (which is relevant here, because `WooCommerce.get(...)` doesn't return a promise, and is thus useless waste of cycles to `await` it).

Comment: In that case, still has a problem this statement: *await only works with functions that return a Promise?* as you said *waste of cycles to await it*. You can use await regardless of whether the called function returns or not a promise. Anyway, I only want to avoid confusion with this kind of statements.

Comment: This is my go to resource on the topic: [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), which also includes discussion on [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description) below. The edited post also has updated references.

Answer (score 0):

hello mate await usually resolves a promise so the function that is being called after the await key word should be a function that returns a promise or an asyn function which by default returns a promise.

Async function

```
WooCommerce.get("orders", async function(err, data, res) {
      return res;
});
```

Or a function that returns a promise

```
WooCommerce.get("orders", function(err, data, res) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
   err ? reject(err) : resolve(res);
  }
});
```